# MYSql replace deleting too many rows.

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me nuts for two days now.

I have a PHP app where there is one customer with lots of shipping addresses. I use replace when updating a shipping address, but when I do, it validly updates the current shipping address, but DELETES every other shipping address for that customer!

Each address has a Pri-Key AddId.

```
        $sql5 = "replace into address (
            addid, 
            addcustid, 
            addtype, 
            address1, 
            address2, 
            addcity, 
            addstate,
            addstateother, 
            addzip, 
            addcountry, 
            addnote)
             values(
            '".$_REQUEST['shipAddId']."', 
            '".$_REQUEST['custId']."', 
            's', 
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipAdd1'])."',     
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipAdd2'])."', 
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipCity'])."', 
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipState'])."', 
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['otherShipState'])."',
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipZip'])."', 
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipCountry'])."',
            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['shipNotes'])."'
            )";
```

on a table with the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`addid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`addcustid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`addtype` enum('b','s') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'b',
`address1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`address2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`addcity` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`addstate` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`addstateother` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`addzip` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`addcountry` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`addnote` tinyblob,
PRIMARY KEY (`addid`),
KEY `add_cust_id_idx` (`addcustid`),
CONSTRAINT `add_cust_id` FOREIGN KEY (`addcustid`) REFERENCES `cust` (`custid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=207 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Nothing else is affected. It is as if we said delete all addresses with the $_REQUEST['custId'] except the address with supplied $_REQUEST['shipAddId'].

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: replace uses the primary key, if that's the customer id, then it will replace all, i suspect UPDATE will solve the problem

Comment: Primary key is addid, which makes this so wierd. It should only replace where addid=$_REQUEST['shipAddId'], but it is replacing where addcustid=$_REQUEST['custId'] which is NOT PK!

Comment: then why not use an UPDATE with `where addid=$_REQUEST['shipAddId'] AND addcustid=$_REQUEST['custId']` Replace does a delete then insert so bonus is it would be faster.

Comment: I guess I wanted the cleanliness of UPDATE using the field list then the value list separately instead of set a=b, c=d where...

Comment: You _should_ do only updates, but those deletes of all of `addcustid` of are weird, _unless_ you do the same on your `cust` table there somewhere, and the `ON DELETE CASCADE` kicks in? Remember, `REPLACE` is a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT`, default foreign key cascades apply.